# removing and replacing observations with string package

Tags: r, str-replace, stringr

I have two datasets, I'm trying to join together. the column i am joining by does not exactly match up with each other. first file the column looks like this: 00:01:54:2145 etc. 00: for every single observation. I want to change all the observations in this column to be in this format: 01/54/2145. 
I have tried several things with string package, but can't get it to work.

```
df1 <- df %>%
   str_replace_all("00:")
```

I'm getting this error, but don't think that's the only problem:
argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

my_conversion <- Vectorize(function(str) {
str_replace(str, "^00:", "") %>%
  str_replace_all(":", "/")
})


df <- data.frame(
  a_column = 1:3, key_column = c("00:01:54:2145", "00:01:54:2145", "00:01:54:2145"))

df %>% mutate(key_column = my_conversion(key_column))
```

Comment: still getting the error: argument is not an atomic vector; coercing